# Calling a function from within itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several elements inside a container. All their events are handled inside a function `events()`.

On click of a button inside the container, I replace the container's html with the response from an AJAX request.

```
function events() {
    $(".btn").on("click", function() {
     ...
    }); 

    $(".txt").on("keyup", function() {
     ...
    });

    $(".btn2").on("click", function() {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                       $(".container").html(xmlhttp.responseText); 
                       events(); // ***
                    }
                }
                url = 'handlers/gethtml.ashx';
                xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
        });
}
```

Now, I need to rebind all the controls with events so after changing the html     `$(".container").html(xmlhttp.responseText);` I call the function within itself because the new html contains the same controls with the same events.

Does this cause stack overflow? I have some performance issues so i was wondering if this maybe the cause. Also, is there any workaround, maybe a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: The if check `if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {` makes no sense if you are not checking for activeX in the else. And you are using jQuery so why in the world are you not using `$.get`?

Comment: Just wondering - why are you using the native `XMLHttpRequest` when you have jQuery? Use `$.ajax()`

Comment: @epascarello I don't much about ajax, i just copy the same peace of code whenever i need it. I'll use `$.get` from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using event delegation, you don't need to bind the event again

```
$(".container").on("click",".btn2", function() {...});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2):

Use event delegation, then no need to rebind the events since it will handle dynamic element as well

You could further shorten the code by using jquery to load the url contents

```
function events() {
    var ct = $(".container");
    ct.on("click", ".btn", function() {
    }); 

    ct.on("keyup", ".txt", function() {
    });

    ct.on("click", ".btn2", function() {
        ct.load('handlers/gethtml.ashx')
    }
```

Comment: `$(".container").on(` is a lot better.

Comment: @JamesMontagne isn't `$(".container").on(` the same as `var ct = $(".container");    ct.on`?

Comment: @enb081 Answer has since been edited.  It was `$(document).on`.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `events()`. It is in the scope!

There are a couple of things you need to be aware of, though:

1. Elements already on there will have two click handlers on the second run - the old, and the new. To get rid of them, use `unbind` to unbind all `click` events, for example.
2. You may want to split up your event creation function further.